# Why are categorical limits and colimits not swapped?

Tags: category-theory, math-history

After having understood direct limits of direct systems and inverse limits of inverse systems, as well as the corresponding categorical notions of colimits and limits, I'm left wondering why the latter are named this way and not swapped.

At least to me, it would make more sense for a "limit" to be something where the arrows come "from" a diagram (as in a direct limit), but that's a *co*limit.

Is there some good reason to define them this way around?
If not, then how did they come to be named this way?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because products and coproducts were named first.

Comment: I agree, T0mstone. But it’s far worse than that! Having appropriated the word “limit”, which people had been happily using in “direct limit” for decades, and inverted its meaning, they then have the cheek to object when people refer to a direct limit because “it’s not a limit, it’s a colimit”!

Comment: P.S. I may have exaggerated how annoyed this makes me.

Comment: … and don’t get me started on (co)equalizer!